# How to create or find a SERVICE_PROJECT_ID in Google Cloud?

Tags: gcloud, vpc, google-cloud-memorystore

So I'm trying to connect a Redis Memorystore instance to Cloud Run through a VPC, so I need to [create a Redis instance on a Shared VPC network from a service project.](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/creating-managing-instances?authuser=1#creating_a_redis_instance_on_a_shared_vpc_network_from_a_service_project)

I have values for all the variables except for `SERVICE_PROJECT_ID`. What is that and how to I create/find one for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable SERVICE_PROJECT_ID refers to a service project in the context of VPC networking. When you use Shared VPC, you designate a project as a host project and attach one or more other service projects to it. The VPC networks in the host project are called Shared VPC networks. Eligible resources from service projects can use subnets in the Shared VPC network. This is detailed in the "Shared VPC overview" [online document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc).